Bounding a quadratic form using projections
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ a positive linear operator, meaning that $\langle x, T x\rangle \ge 0$ holds for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$. Let $M\subset \mathcal{H}$ be a closed subspace, so that $\mathcal{H} = M \oplus M^{\perp}$. Denote by $\pi_{M}$ the projection operator onto $M$. I want to know if the following estimate
$$\langle x, T x \rangle \le C(\langle x, \pi_{M}T\pi_{M}x\rangle + \langle x, \pi_{M^{\perp}}T\pi_{M^{\perp}}x\rangle)$$
holds true for some constant $C>0$. My approach so far is to write $\langle x, Tx \rangle = \langle x, (\pi_{M}+\pi_{M^{\perp}})T(\pi_{M}+\pi_{M^{\perp}})x\rangle$ and bounding the mixed terms using Cauchy-Schwarz, but this led me nowhere so far. Any help?

For $u,v\in \mathcal{H}$ we have
$$|\langle u,Tv\rangle|=|\langle v,Tu\rangle|=|\langle T^{1/2}u,T^{1/2}v\rangle|\\ \le \|T^{1/2}u\|\,  \|T^{1/2}v\| =\langle u,Tu\rangle^{1/2} \langle v,Tv\rangle^{1/2}$$
Therefore
$$ \langle u+v,T(u+v)\rangle =\langle u,Tu\rangle +\langle v,Tv\rangle+\langle u,Tv\rangle+\langle v,Tu\rangle\\
\le \langle u,Tu\rangle +\langle v,Tv\rangle +2\langle u,Tu\rangle^{1/2} \langle v,Tv\rangle^{1/2}\\
=[\langle u,Tu\rangle^{1/2}+ \langle v,Tv\rangle^{1/2}]^2\le 2^{1/2}[\langle u,Tu\rangle+ \langle v,Tv\rangle ]$$ Let $u=\pi_Mx$ and $v=\pi_{M^\perp}x.$ Then $u+v=x.$ Hence
$$\langle x,Tx\rangle \le 2^{1/2}[\langle \pi_Mx,T\pi_Mx\rangle +\langle \pi_{M^\perp}x,T\pi_{M^\perp}x\rangle]\\ =2^{1/2}[\langle x,\pi_MT\pi_Mx\rangle +\langle x,\pi_{M^\perp}T\pi_{M^\perp}x\rangle]$$
Remark We can omit the  application of  the square root. The form $\{u,v\}:=\langle u,Tv\rangle$ is positive definite. Hence it satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, i.e.
$$|\langle u,Tv\rangle|=|\{u,v\}|\le \{u,u\}^{1/2}\{v,v\}^{1/2}=\langle u,Tu\rangle^{1/2} \langle v,Tv\rangle^{1/2} $$
